# Android Studio not auto-completing style attributes for a custom view referenced from a module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-custom-view

**Circumstance:**

I have a custom view I would like to use in several projects, so I package it in a module. I am able to create a new project and set a reference to my module. Android Studio is able to detect referenced classes and the project runs on my device.

**Problem:**

My problem is that Android Studio does not auto complete style attributes for my custom view on the layout edit page.

**What I did:**

- I run assembleRelease task on Gradle.
- Copy the output .aar file into my new project under a directory called 'aars'
- Modify build.gradle file to reference my module

> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     compile(name: 'listapps', ext: 'aar')
> }
>
> repositories {
>     flatDir { dirs 'aars' }
> }
> ```

- I define  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` inside my top level Layout declaration.

**Question:**

How do I fix this? Is there a step I am missing?

**Notes:**

1. I renamed the extension to .zip, and saw that my declare-styleable element exists in the values.xml file.
2. Below is my sample XML snippet, just in case.

> ```
> <com.ahmetkizilay.tests.modules.listapps.AppListerViewGroup
>     android:id="@+id/wgAppLister"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
>     app:intent_data_type="image/*"
>     app:intent_name="android.intent.action.SEND"
>     />
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you copy the '.aar' file? AFAIK marking it a module / android-library should do the trick.

Comment: I plan on using these modules on different projects. I thought .aar is the way to distribute modules besides putting them in the public maven repository.